# Struggling to pass a string from JavaScript to C++ in qtQuick

Tags: javascript, c++, qt-quick

Ive been trying to pass a simple string from JavaScript for several hours now. I've tried everything i can think of and more. I dont know how to use c++ at all but the implementation of JavaScript in QtQuick has no way to save files so i have to use it.
things ive tried:
defining the type of dataDump to be string, char, QString, int
from what i understand char can be a single character however no matter what i pass it from js it comes out as a an empty line in the file i save it to.

string gives the error main.js:12 Error: Unknown method parameter type: string

QString fills the console with over 100 unique errors none of which have any bearing on my project or useful insights as to what is actually wrong, somewhat reminiscent of what happens when missing a close bracket in python, in other words the error is not helpful at all

int, this one works perfectly i can pass an int just fine to the c++ function

I should also say that it writes to the file fine if i replace dataDump on line 29 with "why is c++ this way..." or any other string

TLDR: Ive never used c++ before now how do I call a c++ function from JavaScript passing a string into it as a parameter.

Heres my code:
please ignore the stupid number of includes

cppfunctions.cpp:

```
#include "cppfunctions.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringBuilder>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QString>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stringapiset.h>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
using namespace std;



CPPFunctions::CPPFunctions(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{}

void CPPFunctions::writeToFile(std::ofstream &outputFile, int x)
{
    outputFile << x << endl;
}

void CPPFunctions::save(string dataDump)
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("C:/Users/jorda/Desktop/meme.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    outputFile << dataDump << endl;
    outputFile.close();
}

void CPPFunctions::hello_world() {
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
```

cppfunctions.h:

```
#ifndef CPPFUNCTIONS_H
#define CPPFUNCTIONS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringBuilder>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stringapiset.h>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
using namespace std;



class CPPFunctions : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CPPFunctions(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void writeToFile(std::ofstream &outputFile, int x);
    Q_INVOKABLE void save(string dataDump);
    Q_INVOKABLE void hello_world();

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // CPPFUNCTIONS_H
```

main.js:

```
function randomNumber(){
    var number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).toString()+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).toString();
    return number;
}

function testCPP() {
    cpp.hello_world();
}
function saveCPP(){
    var temp = 1;
    console.log(temp, "temp")
    cpp.save(temp)
}
```